# ASP.NET Access to the path denied, on Web Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5

I am having a problem, that is when I deployed my asp.net 4.0 application on my web server i am unable to write to App_Data folder. Actually it has an xml file which I am trying to write some information into. I am getting the following error.

```
Access to the path 'C:\HostingSpaces\hosterind\mydomain.com\wwwroot\App_Data\ErrorLog.xml' is denied.
```

I tried searching every corner for a possible solution before posting on stackoverflow but i am unable to fix this. Searching similar questions on internet (stackoverflow too) i concluded that i need to handle it through IIS as everywhere it was quoted on internet to grant permission to App_Data folder through IIS Manager. As accessing IIS Manager of your web hosting server is impossible, i supposed people are referring to my local IIS server. So, i copied my project which i was developing in visual studio from location: C:\Users\DanComputer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MyWebProject and pasted  into C:\inetpub\wwwroot. Then i located my project in IIS Manager by selecting DefaultAppPool as application pool. I changed my App_Data folder permission to allow full control for IIS_IUSRS(DanComputer\IISUSRS). Then i copied my App_Data folder to my web hosting space using ftp software but it didn't solve my problem. I tried many thing even changing permission to allow full control for everyone but it did't work and i am still getting the same error. Any help please?

Comment: do you have access to the server to run a console command?

Comment: i didn't ever ask that from my hosting company. actually this is my first application i developed and now getting problem. I dont have much knowledge of IIS and related stuff. How can i know if my server allow running a console command? I am not sure a hosting company can allow this, but still welcome if you have some idea of solving my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know what is the identity of the Application Pool of your app. You can get this information from IIS or console. It is possible that your hosing company may have a control panel that can give you that information.

[image]

Then you need to give permissions to the account in the app pool identity the names will be the same or at least be very similar to what you saw in IIS:

[image]

So using my examples above I will have to give permissions to Local Service or Network Service to read/write my app_data folder.

Comment: Can you tell me what next should i do after knowning my hosting company applicayio pool?

Comment: Thanks, Sounds logical. I did an email to my hosting company to let me know their IIS default application pool. Hopefully this will solve my problem